# ToC links below position of chapter text

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref

In my class notes, which is of `report` class, using the ToC hyperlinks to the chapters sends a pointer right below the chapter text.

How can one anchor the ToC link to the chapters to be above the text?

I tried adding `\phantomsection` before the chapter declarations but that unfortunately didn't work.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[all]{hypcap}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={blue!80!black},
    citecolor={blue!50!black},
    urlcolor={blue!80!black}
}

\titlecontents{chapter}[0em]{\smallskip\bfseries}%\vspace{1cm}%
{}%
{\itshape\bfseries}%numberless%
{\hfill\contentspage}%

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\bfseries\centering\color{BrickRed}}{}{0pt}{\LARGE}[\titlerule]

\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{-75pt}{\parskip}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \chapter{Lecture 1}
    \blindtext
    \newpage
    \chapter{Lecture 2}
    \blindtext
    \newpage
    \blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use sectional unit packages that might be conflicting. Not saying they are, but just check. What happens when you remove [`sectsty`](//ctan.org/pkg/sectsty), since the formatting options are already provided by [`titlesec`](//ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) (which you're using anyway).

Comment: @Werner I wouldn't doubt it. My full lecture notes preamble is full of a lot of things I'm not sure are conflicting or not because I've put it together like a car with duct tape. Because you said that I notice I'm already ```\centering``` in the titelsec commands.. Thanks, I'll remove it